# Search by JObject's properties in array of array and compute the result

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, search

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "Layers": [
        {
            "Name": "Layer 1",
            "Features": [
                {
                    "Name": "Feature 1",
                    "Properties": {
                        "Custom property A": "someValue",
                        "Custom property B": "someValue"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Feature 2",
                    "Properties": {
                        "Custom property A": "someValue",
                        "Custom property B": "someValue"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Layer 2",
            "Features": [
                {
                    "Name": "Feature 1",
                    "Properties": {
                        "Custom property A": "someValue",
                        "Custom property B": "someValue"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Feature 2",
                    "Properties": {
                        "Custom property A": "someValue",
                        "Custom property B": "someValue"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That I've deserialized (using [QuickType](https://quicktype.io/)) into the following classes structure:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Layer> Layers { get; set; }
}

public class Layer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JObject Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Note: you can see that the `Properties` property from the `Feature` class, it's a `JObject` and not another class - that's because the properties that will be held there differ from user to user. It's where this whole issue came from.

**The goal is to check where a certain "custom property" is used (in which layers and in which features). And the name of this custom property is a user input (somewhat like a search).**

For example (using the above data), if a user inputs "Custom property A", I need to show him the following response:

```
The Custom property A is used in:
Layer 1
    Feature 1
    Feature 2
Layer 2
    Feature 1
    Feature 2
```

My first step was to get all the unique custom properties like so:

```
List<string> allProps = _data.Layers.SelectMany(layer => layer.Features)
    .SelectMany(feature => feature.Properties.Properties().Select(jProperty => jProperty.Name))
    .Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToList();
```

Now my second step is to go through `allProps` with a foreach loop and search where that custom property name is used, then store it in an object like this:
`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> dictionary;`
[image: Dictionary explained]

This way, I can access the dictionary at a later point (like `dictionary[userInputCustomPropertyName]`) then compute the response, and not have to process the whole data file each time the user is "searching" because it's kind of a huge file.

The problem is that I just can't figure out what to do in that second step. I've tried any combination of the LINQ methods I could think of but I can't get it to work.
I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me

```
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

    var customProperty = "Custom property A";
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Custom property {customProperty} is used in:");
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (var layer in data.Layers)
    {
        var featureNames = layer.Features
                 .Where(i => i.Properties.Properties()
                 .Any((j => j.Name == customProperty ))).Select(i => i.Name);

        Console.WriteLine(layer.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", featureNames));
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

or shorter ( but not very clear), you don't need any your custom classes

```
    var customProperty = "Custom property A";
    var sb = new StringBuilder($"Custom property \"{customProperty}\" is used in:\n");

    JObject.Parse(json)["Layers"].ToList().ForEach(layer =>
        sb.Append("\n" + layer["Name"] + "\n" +
             string.Join("\n", layer["Features"].Where(i => ((JObject) i["Properties"]).Properties()
              .Any((j => j.Name == customProperty))).Select(i => i["Name"])) + "\n"));

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you @serge! That does indeed work like a charm! I appreciate the help!